# Count number of pairs $(a,b)$ in an array such that $(a + b)$ divides $(a * b)$

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, mathematical-programming

We are given an array of size $N$ with integer entries $> 0$. We have to count the number of all such pairs $(a,b)$ with $a \leq b$ such that $a*b$ is divisible by $a + b$.

The obvious naive way is to check every pair and it takes $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$ time. This seems to be more of a maths problem rather than algorithmic.

Is it possible to improve the time complexity of this problem?

I have this idea.

Let $d = gcd(a,b)$. For some $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $a = dx$ and $b = dy$ with $gcd(x,y) = 1$. Since $gcd(x,x + y) = 1$ and $gcd(y,x + y) = 1$, we have

$(a+b) \lvert ab \Rightarrow d(x+y) \lvert d^2xy \Rightarrow (x+y) \lvert dxy \Rightarrow (x+y) \lvert d$

Let $d = k(x + y)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $a = kx(x+y)$ and $b=ky(x+y)$ and the problem reduces to finding all such triplets $(k,x,y)$ with $x < y$ and $gcd(x,y) = 1$.

Comment: What is the domain of $a$ and $b$? All real integers?

Comment: We can assume the array has only integers $> 0$.

Comment: Please edit the question to incorporate that information into the question.

Comment: I've made an edit.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm, an analysis of some algorithm (which?) or the complexity of the problem? The three are very different (if not unrelated) questions!

Comment: I am looking for an algorithm which can improve upon $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$. I don't know whether such an algorithm exists.

Comment: $(x+y) \lvert dxy \Rightarrow d \lvert (x+y)$ is incorrect. Consider counterexample $x=y=1, d=4$.

Comment: Ohh.. I get it. Then since $gcd(x,x + y) = 1$ and $gcd(y,x + y) = 1$ then it should be the other way round. $(x + y) \lvert d$. It's a typo. Thanks for pointing out. Everything else is ok.

Comment: The information that the elements are integers isn't in the question yet.

Comment: Please don't use "Edit:".  Instead, revise the question to read well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.